# Linking form and button to javascript command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a simple form and button work. I have linked to a JS Fiddle here [View JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/DashDingo/1c93pqj0/)

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="enter sport">
<button type="submit" id="WFFsearch">Search</button>
</form>  

$('#WFFsearch').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#search').text();
    var url = "http://espn.go.com/" + searchInput + "/statistics";
    window.open(url);
});
```

I want to be able to enter "nba" without the quotation marks and click the search button, then have a new window which generates the following link http://espn.go.com/nba/statistics. The first part and the last part of all the urls will be the same, it's just the middle that changes (nba, nfl, mlb). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EzPz! This is a very simple task. First of all though, since you're using jQ to establish your button's click event, you can either drop the attribute `type="submit"`, **OR** (<sub>*recommended*</sub>), create your event on the form's submit. If it were me, I'd id the form and use the forms submit, so that you don't need any alters to your button `type="submit"` and <kbd>enter</kbd> key can still be used in search box to submit the form.

Also, you're trying to `.text` on an input. Input's have `value`. In jQuery you can get *or set* that value by calling `.val()` instead.

The code:

```js
$('#frmGetStats').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var searchInput = $('#search').val(),
      url = "http://espn.go.com/" + searchInput + "/statistics",
      win = window.open(url);
  alert("In this sandbox, new windows don't work. \nHowever you can see the link is \n[" + url + "]");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmGetStats">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="enter sport">
  <button id="WFFsearch" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#WFFsearch').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#search').val();
    var url = "http://espn.go.com/" + searchInput + "/statistics";
    window.open(url);
});
```

You need val() property, since input is in question, not text(). https://jsfiddle.net/1c93pqj0/2/

Answer (score 2):

you wanna use the .val() instead of .text() as text gets the value between 2 tags `<div>here is some text</div>` and val gets the value `<input value="some value"/>`

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an input field, use `.val()`. `.text()` is for the text in a DOM element.

Clicking on the submit button submits the form by default, which reloads the page and kills the script. You need to `return false` from the event handler to prevent this.

```
$('#WFFsearch').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#search').val();
    var url = "http://espn.go.com/" + searchInput + "/statistics";
    window.open(url);
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/e2mw4b32/4/)